# How to tap on a site according to the coordinates obtained by the RBG color of an image?

Tags: python, adb, pyautogui

I am trying to create a kind of bot for a game in which spheres randomly appear in a certain place, the spheres have a specific color, so I can place them with RGB; however, when I try to send them to the function, nothing happens.

This is the code, what am I doing wrong?

I have 1 week learning python in a self-taught way.

```
from ppadb.client import Client
import  time
import keyboard
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui

client = Client(host="127.0.0.1",port=5037)
devices = client.devices()
device_0 = devices[0]


def click(x,y):
    inpu = 'input tap'
    device_0.shell(inpu + ' ' + str(x) + ' ' + str(y))

         
while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:   
                       
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(1285,65,450,690))

    width, height = pic.size

    for x in range(0,width,5): 
        for y in range(0,height,5):
          
            r,g,b = pic.getpixel((x,y))
          
            if b == 129:
                click(x+1285, y+65)
                time.sleep(5)
                break
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Seems like you are using the Android emulator and use Python to create a screen shot. The main problem of the emulator is that the emulator resolution is often higher than the physical resolution of your monitor, so the emulator image is stretched. Better use `adb screencap` command to create a screenshot with the original resolution of the phone. If that still does not work the game may detect the difference between real touches and emulated touches. Not sure if it is possible to send "real touches" via adb.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) only doing a few changes to your script

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import keyboard
import time
from PIL import Image

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, KEY_EVENT

device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    img = device.takeSnapshot(reconnect=True)
    w, h = img.size
    for x in range(0, w, 5): 
        for y in range(0, h, 5):
            r, g, b, a = img.getpixel((x, y))
            if b == 129:
                device.touch(x, y)
                time.sleep(5)
                break
```

Notice that this works either with an emulator or a real device as it's not getting the screenshot from your computer.